# picked image as background in image button and convert to byte

Tags: android, background, byte, android-imagebutton

I need to upload an image in parse picked from the gallery. I use a imageButton to call de intent and to show the image picked and this is working.

```
public class Datos extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {


private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private ImageButton imageView;
byte [] data;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);
    btnClick();

ImageButton pickImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    pickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selectedImage);
                    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);



                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
    }
}

 public void btnClick() {

    Button buttonEnviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);


    buttonEnviar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //Storing image in parse passed in  onclick method of a button with the below code:



            Intent intentDatos = new Intent(Datos.this, Inicio.class);
            startActivity(intentDatos);

            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Musica");


            //data = "".getBytes();
            //byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("selected.png", data);

            testObject.put("imagen", file);

            testObject.saveInBackground();
```

With this code, I show the selected image in the button but it don't replace the background. I don't know how to change the background with the selected image.

Also, with the next code I convert the background into file and I can upload it to parse, but I need to convert the picked image,

```
byte[] data = "".getBytes();
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have bitmap in selectedImage so you can convert it to byte array like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();
```

Secondly you can set background of image button like this:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selectedImage);
 pickImage.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: Hi Aakash, thanks for your help. Your code works and now I have the background with the selected image, but how I pick this background to convert it in byte with Byte [] data = "".getByte(); I always convert the main background fixed and note the selected one,

Comment: i think i have answered your question that how to convert bitmap you are getting into byte away, i am not able to understand, what else problem you are facing

Comment: I had two problems, one, when picked the image it showed above the background predeterminated in the image button, now with your answer the code change the predeterminated background for the picked one. This is solved, the second problem is that I have to upload the picked background (picked image) to parse and the code doesn't work, always uploads the predeterminated background. If you now how to do this,

Comment: I get it, please post the code where you are uploading to parse.com, may be i can help you with that, by the way that was not the part of your question ;)

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code and added your code too. Inside the OnActiviyResult the variable data is never used according with Android Studio and when I test the app, with this code crash, and the log says "NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array", thanks a lot for your support,

Comment: first of all you are opening other activity on button click and it must be giving null pointer exception on data because at that point data will be null. You need to make data a global variable then you should upload the file to parse and in saveinbackground success you should go to another activity

Comment: Sorry, I forget to put in my previous edit the data variable declared, now is edited. Please check if it is well declared. I will look for information of how declare a global variable, I hope this solve the problem,

Comment: you are defining data again inside onActivityResult, correct that by doing data = stream.toByteArray();